# Why window.innerWidth is 'undefined' onComponentMount (React(?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

when i first load my app, my `width` is undefined. It works as expected ONLY after i resize it.

```
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerwidth);
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResizeWindow = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        // subscribe to window resize event "onComponentDidMount"
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResizeWindow);
        return () => {
            // unsubscribe "onComponentDestroy"
            window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResizeWindow);
        };
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        if (width >= 900) {
            dispatch(setView('trip'))
        }
        console.log(width) //prints 'undefined' on initial mount
    }, [width])
```

I am conditionally rendering come components based on `width` but it doesnt work unless i resize.

```
return
  (
    <>
      {width < 900 &&
         <MobileNavbar />
      }
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

##### window does not have `innerwidth` property.

`const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerwidth);` ❌

##### try this, `const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);` ✅